# Look Ahead in Regex for Web Server log?

Tags: python, regex

#### Explanation

In my log I have many of such lines:

```
"[14/Oct/2014:13:02:15 +0200]","70","-","192.168.1.1","/API-1.2/testeo_keyword/vcn,ge/channel,rateber/site,bla_.de/keyword,null/px2.js","?ts=0.3054514767395726", "200","+", "http://www.bla.de/Arzt/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg/328-Heidelberg/Neurochirurgie/","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50527; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8)","-"0/hurlau,superman;tile,4;status,0/pxl.js","?ts=0.3001205851715877", "200","+", "http://www.super.de/news/audio-video/carl-zeiss-praesentiert-3d-brille-100-euro-742545.html","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0","-"
```

#### What to capture?

From the **n - 2nd** field (the one with the URL) I need to capture the domain name and for every `domain name=super.de` I need to collect the whole URL.

#### What do I have?

I have this RegEx: http://regexr.com/39q1b where I managed to capture all I need, but is this correct the way I am doing it? **((match)match)**. Later I need to, *everywhere where domainname="super.de, collect the whole URL*. Also the www is optional. Note: The first URL occurence (www.bla.de) needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that complex regex can be simplified looking at your requirement to capture the URL for every domain `name=super.de`:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?super.de[^"]+(?!.*?super\.de)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jO6oY3/2)

Comment: @SirBenBenji [Have you seen this working demo with your new example?](http://regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/3)

Comment: If this would work with regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/2 it would be great. Also I need this to be more efficient than a lookahead if possible, since I will need to crawl Gigabytes.

Comment: I have already provided you a working demo for your example i.e. http://regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/3 If you want to avoid lookahead then I think for more efficiency it is better to pre-process your data by splitting on comma and only apply non-lookahead regex on a particular element of resulting array.

Comment: Ok if we add two parantheses at the beginning and end, your example will work - http://regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/4

Comment: Also... I would like to hear your thoughts on how to achieve this without lookahead? my regex101 example does exactly that, no?

Comment: Please check my previous comment on an approach to avoid lookahead yes your regex defiitely works with `(` and `)` around my suggested regex.

Comment: Sorry I meant my regexr example, it would avoid lookaeads, agree?  regexr.com/39q1k

Comment: Yes `\[(.*?)\]",".*?",".*?","(.*?)",".*?,.*?,.*?,.*?",".*?", ".*?", "http\:\/\/(((?:www\.)?super\.de)\/.*)","(.*?)"` regex will avoid lookahead but very difficult to maintain regex I would say.

Comment: Another way to simplify that regex is: `^(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*){14}"[^"]*"(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?super.de[^"]+)` See this demo: http://regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/5

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:www\.)?super\.de[^"]*)
```

You can try this to grab the url's with `super.de` as domain.See demo.Use `re.findall` or `re.search`

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/9

Comment: Almost perfect, but this would also capture the whole **wrong** group in cases where super occurs somewhere else than in the n - 2nd group, e.g. the 5th group (it happens).

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/cU3sY9/2 and I only need this to match the n-2nd group, where n=last group.